# Reading manifest file contents of a JAR from Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, jar

Is it possible to read manifest file contents from Javascript. Requirement is to upload a jar file, read the manifest file content and then display different fields based on manifest file in browser (client side) and then send data to server.

Comment: Why do you need to read it in JavaScript?

Comment: @Dave: we are actually making 2 calls to server.. one is look into jar file and then based on that display few fields in UI for more user input and then send the jar file again.. instead of sending jar files 2 times, if I could read the manifest file in javascript itself, then first call to server can be avoided.

Comment: yes, a jar is just a zip file.

Comment: yeah but any idea or sample code about reading manifest file's contents (for ex: version) in javascript only ?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd need to send the file twice.

Comment: What is the JavaScript running in?  Ant?  The server, which is running in a JVM?  If the later, is it using `javax.script` to do JavaScript?

Comment: @girish: use input[type=file] and FileReader() to grab the jar file from the local machine, then http://stuk.github.io/jszip/ can turn the binary zip data into a js object, then you can parse the manifest using string methods or regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example, tested in chrome.
I've never seen a JAR manifest, but the simplistic code below worked on the demo JAR files i found floating around.

That part is not tricky anyway, ripping open the zip and grabbing the file is, and here's one way:

```
<html>
<form><input type=file></form>
<script src="http://stuk.github.io/jszip/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="http://stuk.github.io/jszip/jszip-load.js"></script>
<script src="http://stuk.github.io/jszip/jszip-inflate.js"></script>
<script>

    function getManifest(e){

    var file=e.target.files[0];        
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
       var zip = new JSZip(e.target.result);
       var manifest = zip.files['META-INF/MANIFEST.MF']
           .data
           .trim()
           .split(/\s*\n+\s*/)
           .map(function(a,r){
                   r=a.split(/\s*:\s*/); 
                   this[r[0]] = r[1]; 
                   return this;
           },{})[0];

       alert(JSON.stringify(manifest, null, "\t"));

    };

     reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

document.forms[0].elements[0].onchange=getManifest;

</script>
</html>
```

of course, you'll want to swap out the file input for a binary ajax call, but it's about impossible to demo such interaction in a paragraph of code like a file input allows...

it's pretty easy, thanks to jszip. about that: see http://stuk.github.io/jszip/ for general info and http://stuk.github.io/jszip/examples/get-binary-files-xhr2.html for a binary ajax demo.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you talk about Java server app:

No it's not possible.

You need to expose the info from manifest somehow, e.g. through a REST API. See [RestEasy|http://www.jboss.org/resteasy].

And then read it through `XmlHttpRequest`.

PS: It's not a good idea to expose whatever in META-INF or WEB-INF - it's a security risk.